# Why is this regex failing when adding anchors?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is a match:

```
preg_match('/[a-bA-B0-9]+/', 'username')
```

But this is not:

```
preg_match('/^[a-bA-B0-9]+$/', 'username')
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you testing the actual literal `'username'`?

`/[a-bA-B0-9]+/` will test the existence of a,b,A,B,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 *anywhere* in the string. So it will match `abBa854Abba32`, and it will match `sjfsgfafnvesv`.

`/^[a-bA-B0-9]+$/` will test that the *enitre* string is made of a,b,A,B,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. So it will match `abBa854Abba32`, and it will not match `sjfsgfafnvesv`.

Perhaps you meant `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But why didn't it fail in the first example? D:

Comment: because `'username'` contains an `a`.

Answer (score 2):

The second does not match because you have told the regex to match a sequence that *starts* with one of those items in the character class. The first letter of your string is "u", and there is no "u" in your character class [a-bA-B0-9].

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=/%5Ba-bA-B0-9%5D%2b/&subject=username)

You can see that it only matches `a`:

> Results
>
> 1 match was found:
>
> Array (
>       [0] => a )