# Regular expression for amount always returns true

Tags: php, regex

I'm not very familiar with regex. Can someone tell me why I always get **true** for result? In regex101 this works.. This is my input **dd(crb_is_valid_amount( '1234567.'));**
This is my function for validating amount:

```
function crb_is_valid_amount( $amount ) {
if ( preg_match( '/([\d]{1,6})(\.[\d]{2})?/', $amount ) )
{
 return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `'`s

Comment: I tried. Same result.

Comment: The regular expression accepts only 6 digits for the first part. `crb_is_valid_amount('111112.12')` will return true.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want the part before the dot accepts from 1 to 6 digits. The second group has to be optional, but if you input the second group it has to be with dot and it has to take only two digits. I just perform my regex and now it always returns true ** '/([\d]{1,6})(\.[\d]{2})?/' ** , ** dd(crb_is_valid_amount( '1234567.')); **

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why preg\_match() always validates as true when partial match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318599/why-preg-match-always-validates-as-true-when-partial-match) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134512/why-is-this-regex-failing-when-adding-anchors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `^` and `$` the specify the beginning and the end of the string

```
function crb_is_valid_amount( $amount ) {
    return preg_match('/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{2})?$/', $amount) ;
}

var_dump(crb_is_valid_amount('112.12')); // 1
var_dump(crb_is_valid_amount('1234567.')); // 0
```

Your original regular expression returns true for the second case, because `'1234567.'` **contains 6 digits**, but doesn't take care of what's after the 6 first digits. Using `^` and `$` checks if the given string matches exactly with the expression, from start to end.

Means:

```
^\d{1,6}     # Begins with 1 to 6 digits,
(\.\d{2})?   # Optionally with a dot and 2 digits,
$            # End of given string (nothing after accepted).
```

Comment: As revo has posted, character classes are not needed.

Comment: Don't need first capturing group

Comment: @mickmackusa Right again ;) Thank you.

Comment: Please include an explanation for why the original pattern was always matching.

Comment: Did you test your code?  Need to force the bool value right?  See revo's answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've tested. Of course return 1 or 0. Casting to boolean will works because preg_match() returns 0, 1 or false.

Comment: My concern is that your answer is misrepresenting the output.

Answer (score 3):

You should use beginning and ending of string anchors along with `\d{1,6}`

```
function crb_is_valid_amount($amount) {
    return preg_match('/^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{2})?$/', $amount) === 1 ? true : false;
}
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/NVleZ)

Comment: Yes, OP doesn't need it. @mickmackusa